# Can non-linear dependence be detected between two variables by regressing them?

Tags: regression, correlation, nonlinear, qq-plot

Linear regression is meant for linear relationships right, so, if I don't trust linear correlation and want to find out if random variables $y$ and $x$ have a non-linear relationship, can't I just regress $y$ against $x$ without intercept like so, $y = \beta x + \epsilon$, and then use a **QQ plot of the residuals** to see that a divergence from the 45-degree line indicates non-linearity. Otherwise, maybe some other related post-regression test?

Comment: Linear regression means linear in the parameters. Just plotting the original data is a more direct alternative here.

Comment: linear in parameters, not linear in variables, ok

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the QQ plot doesn't tell you about the relationship between y and x's, it tells you about the distribution of the residuals (which should reflect the errors if the model is otherwise correct, if the QQ plot doesn't look fairly close to linear the residuals are not close to what you'd expect if the errors were normally distributed).

Residual plot(s) tell you about non-linearity is the relationship between y and the corresponding x variable(s).

Here's what you could see for an example set of data with mild non-linearity in it.

[image: Example plot of y vs x, residuals vs x and qq plot]

Here there is a bit of non-linearity (because I put it in the data), but it is not totally obvious in the plot of y vs x.

If the linear model were correct the residuals should appear to be randomly scattered above and below 0 at each x-value.

It is not the case here -- in the plot of residuals vs x you can see the curvature clearly. I marked in a quadratic curve but you'd more typically look at a smooth fit to the residuals for such a purpose.

The QQ plot looks linear here but it is not readily interpretable because of the issue in the residual plot.

(There are better things to plot than raw residuals but let's get the more basic concepts clear to begin with.)

Comment: so how to infer presence of nonlinearity from residual plots instead

Comment: answer edited. Do you use R?

Comment: python mainly. in the second graph with the red regression line, how were you able to run linear regression (`lm`) and produce a curved non-linear regression line?

Answer (score 5):

Before even getting to regression modelling, if you just have two scalar variables then you should start with a **scatterplot** of $x$ and $y$.  That is likely to immediately tell you if they have a "linear" (or perhaps "affine") relationship.  It is of course possible to follow this up with a formal regression model to test for non-linearity between the two variables; one way to do this is to fit a polynomial regression and test whether the higher-order coefficients (and constant term) are all equal to zero.

Comment: what in a scatter plot of two time series would indicate non-linearity?

Comment: Linearity would mean that $x$ and $y$ roughly follow a straight line through the origin, so anything that looks like it violates that would be evidence of non-linearity.  (If you actually mean an *affine* relationship then the straight line does not have to go through the origin.)

Comment: @develarist Be very careful about naive use of regression with time series data.

Comment: how about scatter plot on time series data like what you were saying

Comment: @develarist See https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/14261/8891 for an example of time series having an apparent linear relationship where there was little or no relationship between the changes of the two variables

Comment: changes in variables is a stronger nonlinearity test than the variables themselves? why

Comment: @Ben here is a follow up question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487148/how-to-use-a-scatter-plot-to-detect-non-linear-co-dependence-between-two-variabl