# How to use a scatter plot to detect non-linear co-dependence between two variables?

Tags: time-series, correlation, data-visualization, nonlinear, scatterplot

A scatter plot  matrix of 3 time series (financial returns data) are shown below. It is a multivariate representation of a scatter plot, with the individual pairs shown in the off-diagonals.

[image]

The plots are augmented with ellipses that cover 95% of the data. If two variables are independent, we would have seen a perfect circle, rather than an ellipse. The narrower the ellipse, the stronger the linear association (correlation) between the two variables.

If using a scatter plot is a way of detecting non-linear dependence between two random variables, then what can be inferred from the individual scatter plots shown in the matrix? Do any of the pairs of return series have non-linear co-dependence? linear co-dependence?  How can you tell.

After the scatterplot, what would be the next step to quantify the linear and non-linear dependencies as numerical values?

Comment: First, continue augmenting the scatterplots---with a linear (regression) line, a nonparametric smoother. A measure of non linearity is the degree to which the nonparametric smotth fits better than the linear.

Comment: what are some nonparametric smoothers?

Comment: splines, lowess, generalized additive models (gam's),   ..., see [this stored search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=nonparametric+smoothing+answers%3A1).

Comment: Which of them are best for nonlinear variables, not nonlinear parameters

Comment: Hard to say, try out some different ones!  but I would start out with a simple one like lowess/loess.  To say more we would need some more context---maybe try some and augment your post with an augmented plot?

Comment: These are time series, and you've left time out!  I don't think this approach is going to be fruitful here (but it will be in other contexts).