# Linear model with both additive and multiplicative effects

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, linear

In linear regression, the independent variables have an additive effect on the response (level-level regression):

$y=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\epsilon$

In a log-level regression, the independent variables have an additive effect on the log-transformed response and a multiplicative effect on the original untransformed response:

$log(y)=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\epsilon$

Suppose that I know for each predictor if it has an additive or multiplicative effect on the response and that I need to estimate these effects through ordinary least squares. How can I specify the formula of the model so that I estimate correctly these effects?

Comment: The two models you posit are inconsistent in how they treat the random error: do you want that to be multiplicative or additive?  For instance, if it's additive then your model will be of the form $$y = \exp(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_1 + \cdots + \alpha_p x_p) + \beta_0 + \beta_1 z_1 + \cdots + \beta_q z_q + \varepsilon,$$ exhibiting multiplicative effects in the $x_i$ and additive effects in the $z_j.$

Comment: @whuber would it be possible to do something like $y = exp(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_1 + \cdots + \alpha_p x_p) + \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \beta_q x_q + \epsilon$? Or, include a multiplicative error as well as kind of a mixed model?

Comment: @Abalter With some care, yes -- although it might be difficult to tease out the separate error terms. I think some extremely specific (and unusual) assumptions about their joint distributions would be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linear Regression to model any linear/non-linear relationship using [basis expansion](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Etibs/stat315a/LECTURES/chap5.pdf) (slides from Elements of Statistical Learning). In your case you could probably exponentiate some of the variables, but it might be preferable to use an automatic method, such as [Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines](http://uc-r.github.io/mars), that still provides interpretable results.

Comment: in the top answer to the following unrelated question, a linear regression plot (second graph) shows a non-linear regression line shown in red. how can a linear regression model produce a non-linear curve for a regression line when we know that regression lines from a linear regression model can only be straight? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487005/can-non-linear-dependence-be-detected-between-two-variables-by-regressing-them

Comment: What basis expansion of the predictors (not the outcome) would allow you to model a multiplicative effect?

Comment: @develarist you can perform linear regression against a _nonlinear function_ of the explanatory variables. If the real, but unknown natural relationship is something like $y = a + b \cdot sin(x) + c \cdot cos(x^2)$, then you can perform linear regression on a formula such as that.

Comment: @Devel I explain this phenomenon, with illustrations, at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/354256/919. The short answer is, *when the regressor variables are non-linearly related, then a linear function of those variables typically looks like a nonlinear function of any proper subset of those variables.*

Comment: @whuber just to be sure since I would like to replicate your linked example for my own data pairs: when you say "regressor variables" in the context of your linked example, do you mean non-linear "regressor variables" as in dependent variable $y$ and independent variable $x$, or "regressor variables" as in $x$ and its transformation $x^2$?

Comment: The ordinary least squares model doesn't care, in any way, whether the second regressor variable $x^2$ is a function of $x.$ Indeed, in old software one often had to process the data to create a separate column to hold the values of $x^2$ and then perform a multiple regression of the $y$ values against the $x$ values and the values in the second column. This little anecdote might help clarify the boundary between *conducting a statistical procedure* (such as OLS regression) and *interpreting its output:* only at the latter stage will you account for the relation between the regressors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible in general to do this with ordinary least squares, since OLS is at heart a trick to calculate $\hat \beta$ in $E[y] = \bf{X}\hat\beta$ using matrix division.

It can be done more generally, though.

I think the tricky bit is figuring out exactly what you mean by *each predictor having an additive or multiplicative effect on the response*. For example, with two predictors, do you mean:

$$
y = (\beta_0 \times \beta_2 x_2) + \beta_1 x_1 ?\\
y = (\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1) \times \beta_2 x_2 ?\\
y = \beta_0 + (\beta_1 x_1 \times \beta_2 x_2) ? \\
$$

...and there's probably others as well. Of these, the first  (multiplication before applying the additive effects) is the simplest to estimate, as it has fewer high-order multiplicative terms, and is more likely to correspond to the model you intended.

Unfortunately, even this isn't simple to estimate, since the predictions with $\beta_0 = 2, \beta_2 = 2$ → $y = (2 \times 2 \times x_2) + \beta_1 x_1$
are the same as those when
$\beta_0 = 1, \beta_2 = 4$ → $y = (1 \times 4 \times x_2) + \beta_1 x_1$.

The best way around this is to use
a Bayesian estimation tool like Stan
to set reasonable priors on your model parameters
(for example that the multiplicative effect, $\beta_2$, should be close to 1),
and find the best parameter estimates that are consistent with those priors.

Comment: You are considering additive models with interactions.  The usual meaning of a "multiplicative effect" is that the model satisfies a partial differential equation $\partial y/\partial x_i = \alpha_i y.$

Comment: I'm not familiar with this framing, thanks. Does the first model not satisfy this, since $\partial y/\partial x_2 = \beta_2 y$?

Comment: In your first model $\partial y/\partial x_2 = \beta_0\beta_2$ is not a constant multiple of $y.$ In fact, all three of your models are standard regression models but have been overparameterized; none of them is a multiplicative effects model.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll come back to this (and amend or remove my answer) tomorrow.